# Facebook object debugger doesn't recognize &colon;

Tags: html, facebook, character-entities

OK, I have an ":" in the page title so I use the HTML5 character entity for it viz. `&colon;`

Facebook's og scraper doesn't seem to recognize it and converts it to a `&amp;colon;`

Here's an example:

[Source](http://jsbin.com/wimel/1/edit)

[FB scraper result](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fjsbin.com%2Fwimel%2F1)

How do I fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed by *not* converting `:` to its html5 entity. Only converting quotes(double & single) might be enough in most cases.